# Issues trying to execute bash script on windows using cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to run a bash script on Windows 7, using cygwin. The script takes two lists of file destinations (files are the same sprinkled in different pairs of folders), iterates through them and detects if the files changed.

```
#!/bin/bash
src=(
  "./src/index.js"
  "./src/index_2.js"
)
dest=(
  "./client/src/index.js"
  "./client/src/index_2.js"
)

arraylength=${#src[@]};

for (( i=0; i<${arraylength}; i++ )); 
do
  DIFF=$(diff -u ${src[$i]} ${dest[$i]})
  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    echo "$DIFF"
    echo "Files ${src[$i]} and ${dest[$i]} are not equal!"
    exit 1
  fi
done
echo "All files are equal"
```

When I run the command like `./shareddiff.sh`, the command executes without errors, but displays nothing (no echo message). Even when I manualy change one of the `index.js` or `index_2.js` files - it doesn't detect the change.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing diff in passing the file arguments; you can compare two files or two directories, not two list of files.

```
SYNOPSIS
       diff [OPTION]... FILES

 FILES are 'FILE1 FILE2' or 'DIR1 DIR2' or 'DIR FILE' or 'FILE DIR'.  If
       --from-file or  --to-file  is  given,  there  are  no  restrictions  on
       FILE(s).   If  a FILE is '-', read standard input.  Exit status is 0 if
       inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble.
```

try

```
 diff -uR src client/src
```

Comment: Shouldn't this part of the code `DIFF=$(diff -u ${src[$i]} ${dest[$i]})` and all below it work?
  
Even if I replace the whole script with one simple echo, like `echo "Hello World"`, I don't see any output.

Comment: If echo does not work is not a diff issue. What terminal are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Cygwin.